# The expression "so wahr ich hier stehe"

Tags: meaning

> Du eilst ihr zu Hilfe, **so wahr ich hier stehe**.

The speaker said this sentece to his interlocutor who shouldn't be wasting any time in going to her rescue but instead seems quite laid-back.

All the  meanings of this expression that I've come across so far do not seem to match this particular example completely.

Comment: This sentence is correct but the phrase *so wahr ich hier stehe* requires a statement about oneself, not about someone else. The only way that sentence fulfils that requirement is *Du eilst ihr zur Hilfe* being a command. The exclamation mark is missing.

Comment: But what is your question?

Comment: Which meanings did you find, and why do you think they don't fit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"So wahr ich hier stehe" is stating that the speaker is absolutely sure about her claim. It is derived from the formula used to take oath "So wahr mir Gott helfe". With this context in mind, it also transports some sort of justification, or defiantness. The speaker tries to arm her claim by saying "So wahr ich hier stehe".

The sentence you cite makes sense, when you do not understand it as an *assertiv*, but rather as a *directive* sentence. Here the formally assertive sentence expresses an expectation. This is the same as when somebody uses "Du gehst jetzt nach Hause!" instead auf "Geh jetzt nach Hause!". In your sentence, "Du eilst ihr zu Hilfe!" is used instead of "Eil ihr zu Hilfe!"

Answer (score 0):

This particular example doesn't make a lot of sense.

> ...so wahr ich hier stehe

is a phrase that acts as an strong assertion of a vow that someone gives. So it doesn't fit to anyone else's actions, but can rather only be used for statements about someone's own behavior. It's a statement of truth and also used in oaths.

> Das ist die Wahrheit, so wahr ich hier stehe.

Would be a valid usage.

Used in a context as in your example, the phrase doesn't make any sense - Why should someone confirm someone else's *present* actions that everyone else can see under oath?

Comment: Es ist eine Drohung, deshalb. "Du willst ihr nicht helfen, aber ich will, dass Du ihr hilfst, und ich sorge dafür, dass Du tust, was ich sage! Beim Bart des Prpheten!"

Comment: @userunknown Ist es das? Ich beneide deine lebhafte Phantasie - Du machst ja ein Drehbuch draus...

Comment: userunknown hat schon Recht, @tofro Das ist ein Beispiel für die Griceschen Konversationsmaximen (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konversationsmaximen) Dass der Satz als Aussage (assertiv) keinen Sinn ergibt, ist ein starkes Indiz dafür, dass er als Aufforderung (direktiv) gemeint ist.

Comment: @tofro: Es gab vom Fragesteller keinen Hinweis darauf, dass an der Sprachkompetenz desjenigen, der das schrieb, zu zweifeln ist. Die außergewöhnliche Situation ist ein Hinweis darauf, dass es sich nicht um einen Satz aus persönlichem Erleben handelt, sondern eher aus einem Buch/Film/Hörspiel. Also sucht mein Hirn erst mal nach einer Interpretation, die mit allen Informationen die ich habe vereinbar ist, bevor ich den Satz für einen Fehler halte. Eine andere Interpretation wäre noch, dass der Zwang/die Bedrohung von dritter Seite kommt, und der Sprecher sieht es schon kommen.